# Sending Google Form response programmatically via Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I've developed a couple other apps that did nothing more than preference management, some custom lists, and LAN communications but that's about it. I'm building a employee attendance app that allows the employee to register when they clock in, lunch out, lunch in, and clock out, all via the app. Once all four have been entered, I want it to send it via a Google Form to a Google spreadsheet that I can then use to calculate there hours and have a long on all of their information.

How would I go about integrating submitting a Google Form Response programmatically in Android?

Thanks in advance, -John

Answer (score 2):

A Google Form is just a fancy UI for having users submit responses which get stored as a Google spreadsheet. That's it - there's nothing special about it. To accomplish this on Android you just need to setup your UI with the appropriate widgets to capture responses. Then save that data to a Google spreadsheet.

To work with the Google Spreadsheet API you can check out [this guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) from Google.

Comment: Thanks for your respnose! I looked at the spreadsheet documentation from google, but I couldn't find where to find and add teh libraries necessary to do this in android. (I'm using eclipse android sdk)

Comment: this was actual question "How would I go about integrating submitting a Google Form Response programmatically in Android?"  what i also need to know.